# Get the computation of first two rows as third row using SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

A sub-query gives following output(only two rows):

```
id | cp  | sp  |
----------------
1  | 200 | 300 |
----------------
2  | 400 | 350 |
```

from above table, how can i get following output:
i.e. Union of first table and **third row=(row1/row2)*100**

```
id | cp  | sp  |
----------------
1  | 200 | 300 |
----------------
2  | 400 | 350 |
----------------
3  | 50  |85.71|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Redshift, I think you need `union all`:

```
select id, cp, sp
from t
union all
select max(id) + 1, 
       max(case when id = 1 then cp end) * 100.0 / max(case when id = 2 then cp end),
       max(case when id = 1 then sp end) * 100.0 / max(case when id = 2 then sp end)
from t
```

Comment: Thanks. What can be the efficient query when the sub-query to compute `t` is very long?

Comment: @xanjay . . . You can try a CTE.  That gives Redshift the opportunity to materialize it if it wants.

Comment: Redshift doesn't ever materialise a CTE in my experience. (unlike postgres)

Comment: @JonScott . . . (I fully believe you.)  Do you know if there is any documentation that describes this.  Amazon goes out of its way to define CTEs as "temporary tables" (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html).

Comment: i have run many experiments with AWS support also on a chat (we were discussing the new features for concurrency scaling - which does not work with temp tables - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/concurrency-scaling.html) - AWS support were telling me that CTE DID produce temp tables but im sure they are incorrect and they agreed in the end. However temp tables ARE created when you use correlated subqueries (which cause concurrency scaling to not kick in). you can use EXPLAIN to see this. Concurrency scaling does work with any CTEs i have tried - including complex examples.

Comment: also - on your link see this statement "Each subquery defines a temporary table, similar to a view definition".. they are a bit confused i think ! :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using either a union or [subquery](https://www.essentialsql.com/how-do-i-combine-results-from-more-than-one-table/). Basically you create write query A which produces the top table and the query B which sums query A's columns. Then, using either union or a subquery you append query B's rows to the bottom of A's rows.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to compute third row for other computations except using built in aggregate functions?